# Applescript dictionary does not contain "open location?" How is that phrase found?

Tags: dictionary, applescript, missing-features

I'm trying to use the directions. From the web I swiped:

tell application "Safari"
    open location "www.hulu.com"
end tell

I can only find "open" in the dictionary and I can't find "location" in the document or as a phrase. What am I missing? How would I find "open location" without resorting to searching the web? It should be in the dictionary somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open location does not belong to Safari. Look in StandardAdditions.

Comment: Not exactly true. Many web-related apps (Safari, Mail, etc) implement "Get URL" (`GURLGURL`) handlers for opening a URL in that app, but annoyingly forget to document it in their dictionaries. The Standard Additions osax also provides a `GURLGURL` handler, which accepts any URL and forwards it to the default app for that URL scheme (e.g. `http` to your default browser.) But you can send a `GURLGURL` event directly to a specific app if you prefer. And since osax terminology is globally available, you can write it as `open location` instead of `«event GURLGURL»` (as long as StdAdds is loaded).

Comment: Can't you send a standard additions command to most apps? tell application "Safari" to display dialog "Standard Additions" Does the command belong to the app or is it a standard addition command being sent to the app?

Comment: `sysodlog` (display dialog) is a Standard Additions handler which can be loaded into _any_ unprivileged process, allowing that process to respond to `sysodlog` events. (Yes, this is evil.) AppleScript automatically tells a process to load osaxen by first sending it an `ascrgdut` event. OTOH, apps like Safari and Mail already contain their own `GURLGURL` (open location) handlers, each one knowing how to open URLs appropriate to that app (`http`, `mailto`, etc). All the Standard Additions' `open location` handler knows how to do is forward a `GURLGURL` event to the default app for that URL.

Comment: If you're really curious, you can test this yourself via appscript's low-level aem module. The following always opens a URL in Safari: `Application('/Applications/Safari.app').event('GURLGURL', {'----':"google.com"}).send()`. However, the following displays a dialog in Safari _only_ if the `display dialog` osax is already loaded: `Application('/Applications/Safari.app').event('sysodlog', {'----':"hello!"}).send()`. Otherwise you get error -1708, event not handled, in which case run `Application('/Applications/Safari.app').event('ascrgdut').send()`, then send the `sysodlog` event again.

Comment: Like I say, it'd be much easier for users to follow if developers'd remember to document their applications' `open location` event handlers in their dictionaries. I suspect they overlook it because Cocoa Scripting already provides Standard Suite definitions for all of the other standard events (`open`, `quit`, etc). Feel free to file bug reports on Safari, Mail, and any other "AppleScriptable" apps that know how to open URLs but don't document it in their dictionaries.